# How can I get the name of the program that is opened with a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file, and I want to *drag* / *"open with"* a program.
For example, if I have a file called `file.abc` and I press `open with...` and select the batch script, how can I get the name `file.abc` inside of the batch script?

Answer (score 1):

Use the special `%1` variable to get the path to the current file.

Write `%~n1` to get just the filename without the extension.

Write `%~n1%~x1` to get the filename and extension.

Also possible to write `%~nx1` to get the filename and extension.

---

Code:

```
@echo off

set bat_name=%~n0 &::Get name of bat file
set bat_full_name=%~nx0 &::Get Name + extenstion (name.bat)
set bat_path=%0 &::Get path of bat file

set file_name=%~n1 
set file_full_name=%~nx1
set file_path=%1

echo You opened %file_name% in %bat_name%
echo You opened %file_full_name% in %bat_full_name%
echo bat path is : %bat_path%
echo file path is : %file_path%

pause
```

Output:

```
You opened file in testbatch
You opened file.abc.lnk in testbatch.bat
bat path is : "C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\Desktop\testbatch.bat"
file path is : C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\Desktop\file.abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in an automatic variable $1 like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Usage:
#   my_batch.sh <file>
#

FILE_NAME="$1"

cat $FILENAME
```

Comment: Sorry, but the unclear question was about referencing arguments passed to a __Windows batch__ file and not about a *bash* script solution. Please click on gray displayed __Delete__ link of your answer which is unfortunately wrong for the question related to Windows batch file argument usage.